# Is any irrational algebraic number normal number?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, normal-number

Suppose number$R$ expands in decimal,and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{C_{n}(d)}{n}=\frac{1}{10}$ where $d$ is one of the ten digit,and ${C_{n}(d)}$  the counting numbers of $d$ from first digit to $n$ digit.We call such a number as normal number.

Now, could any one give any irrational algebraic number $x$ which is a normal number?.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Normal Number - Intuition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/457183/normal-number-intuition)

Comment: This property is called normality in numbers. There are already a huge number of questions about it. One in particular gives that almost all numbers are normal, so any irrational algebraic number is almost certain to also be normal. But it is not yet shown that a specific given number is normal for sure.

Comment: @Nij, am I missing something?  I don't see anything in the link about the question of whether there exists an irrational algebraic number which is normal.  Also your second comment might be confusing to someone unfamiliar with the subject (since we *do* know that some "specific given numbers" are normal.)

Comment: @DanielMcLaury I think Nij is confused, and I suspect the question is open. I guess there is not irrational algebraic number which is normal.

Comment: @XL_at_China: The question is open according to Wikipedia, but presumably *every* irrational algebraic number is normal.  It would be *very* surprising if that weren't the case.

Comment: @Nij could you give any example? Why do you think it is solved? and actually, I do not know the terminology and basic knowledge,sorry.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury in the context of irrational algebraics, we have no known examples, though we expect (almost) all of them to be normal. But I agree that my original phrasing could cause confusion.

Comment: @XL_at_China that's the point, *it is **not** solved*, though we have good reason to expect the result in previous comments vis-à-vis "(almost) all irrational algebraics are normal".

Comment: @DanielMcLaury I suspect there is no irrational algebraic number which is normal when I study another problem, so I ask the question

Comment: We can easily constuct normal rational number of base 10, and construct normal transcendental number of 10 easily, But we have not found or constructed any normal irrational algebraic number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to Wikipedia this is an open question:

> It has been conjectured that every irrational algebraic number is normal; while no counterexamples are known, there also exists no [irrational] algebraic number that has been proven to be normal in any base.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number

Comment: The passage I quoted says the answer to your question is unknown.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation

Comment: http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0304397501001700/1-s2.0-S0304397501001700-main.pdf?_tid=c167d99a-85c6-11e7-80b4-00000aacb35d&acdnat=1503247615_51be8691cedbdb7f66c22741545283cf

Comment: http://www.emis.de/journals/EM/expmath/volumes/11/11.4/pp527_546.pdf